# Derivative of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, markov-chains, fake-proofs, conditional-expectation

Let $\left( {{X_t}:t \in \left[ 0 \right.\left. {, + \infty } \right\rangle } \right)$ be a continuous time Markov chain on a probability space $\left( {\Omega ,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}} \right)$ with a finite state space $S$, defined by jump chain/holding times definition. Suppose $A,B \in \sigma \left( {{X_0}} \right)$ and $f\left( t \right) = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)|B} \right]$ is a decreasing function. Suppose I want to calculate $f'\left( t \right)$. We can assume that $f'\left( t \right)$ is always finite.

There are two ways to go about this, and the other one is probably wrong, but I want to know why.

1) Since $S$ is finite,

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)|B} \right] = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{X_t} = x|B} \right)}  \Rightarrow f'\left( t \right) = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{X_t} = x|B} \right)} \right)} $.

2) Since ${f'}$ is finite, $\frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{E}\left[ {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)|B} \right]$ is finite so $\frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)$ is finite $\mathbb{P}\left( { \cdot |B} \right)$-almost surely. Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem then implies $f'\left( t \right) = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)|B} \right] = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right)} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{X_t} = x|B} \right)} $.

Suppose 1) and 2) are both true. That would imply $\sum\limits_{x \in S} {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right)\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\mathbb{P}\left( {{X_t} = x|B} \right)} \right)}  = 0$, which I have strong reasons to believe is wrong.

Suppose that my line of reasoning is wrong when I conclude that differentiation and expectation commute. Does 2) hold when they do commute? Under what (usual) applicable assumptions do they commute?

EDIT: The following holds for a discrete random variable $X$: $\mathbb{E}\left[ {g\left( X \right)} \right] = \sum\limits_x {g\left( x \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {g\left( X \right) = g\left( x \right)} \right)}  = \sum\limits_x {g\left( x \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {X = x} \right)} $, where the first equality follows from definition, and the second is [the law of unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Let $g\left( x \right) = \frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X^{\left( t \right)}} = x} \right)$, then $\mathbb{E}\left[ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X^{\left( t \right)}}} \right)|B} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {g\left( {{X^{\left( t \right)}}} \right)|B} \right] = \sum\limits_x {g\left( x \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{X^{\left( t \right)}} = x|B} \right)}  = \sum\limits_x {\left( {\frac{d}{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X^{\left( t \right)}} = x} \right)} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{X^{\left( t \right)}} = x|B} \right)} $.

Comment: Your 2. is wrong. How would you justify the second = sign when computing $f'(t)$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{y = g\left( x \right)} {y\mathbb{P}\left( {g\left( X \right) = y} \right)}  = \sum\limits_x {g\left( x \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {X = x} \right)} $

Comment: ?? Please be much more specific (and I am sorry but the formula in your comment is not true).

Comment: Sorry, my connection became horrendous, I'm writing from my phone now. It is called the law of unconscious statistician and it is true

Comment: No. Re-read what you wrote, which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: I don't see it, how should it be restated?

Comment: To begin with, the LHS depends on $x$ while the RHS does not. Anyway this identity, even once corrected, does not obviously provide your 2., does it?

Comment: I've edited in the in-between steps, I see no difficulties there. Neither side depends on $x$ since it is the summation index.

Comment: You might be using $$\sum_{y=g(x)}A(y)$$ with in mind something different from what it actually means. (Point already explained.) Hence you should explain what you mean by this notation. (As already said.) Let me add that I have no incentive to force you to see the light if your main concern is to stonewall the approach (2.) against criticisms, although (2.) is at present squarely wrong.

Comment: I know it is wrong, hence the question. What I want to know where exactly the mistake is, and currently I don't see it at the place you've noted.

Comment: And to explain the meaning of summation: Sum is over all real $x$ grouped so that their image by $g$ is equal (to $y$)

Comment: If the first equality is too confusing, you can ignore it altogether and read only the second and the third equality

Comment: Did, the place you have indicated as problematic before is fine. The actual problem is indicated in the answer below

Comment: @Did: I am afraid I do not know enough to diagnose the error in (2), but my curiosity is piqued. Could you briefly point it out to me? Please feel free to email me if you'd prefer not to respond here. Thanks -

Comment: @CarlMummert This is a matter of going back to the definitions of conditional expectation in the discrete case. Assertion (2) is based on the false premise that $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}P(A\mid X_t)=\sum_x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(P(A\mid X_t=x)\right)\,\mathbf 1_{X_t=x}.$$ Since, by definition, $$P(A\mid X_t)=\sum_xP(A\mid X_t=x)\,\mathbf 1_{X_t=x},$$ one sees that (2) basically asserts that $$(u(t)v(t))'=u'(t)v(t).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality $$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\frac{d}
{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right)|B} \right] = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\mathbb{P}\left( {{X_t} = x|B} \right)\frac{d}
{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right)} $$ 
is wrong since 
$$\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right) = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right){1_{\left\{ {{X_t} = x} \right\}}}} $$ 
so 
$$\frac{d}
{{dt}}\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t}} \right) = \sum\limits_{x \in S} {\frac{d}
{{dt}}\left( {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|{X_t} = x} \right){1_{\left\{ {{X_t} = x} \right\}}}} \right)} $$

The random variable ${{1_{\left\{ {{X_t} = x} \right\}}}}$ also depends on $t$, which I've accidentally ignored.